# Translating "I don't trust you" (said casually)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, definiciones

I have heard that `confiar` is a strong word, implying trust and confidence in someone or something. What then is the right way to translate more casual uses of the word "trust"?

For example, let's say a child tells you to close your eyes and open your mouth so he can feed you a piece of candy. A common response would be `I don't trust you`, which isn't meant in a serious way:

> You're an untrustworthy person, so I refuse to do that.

but a lighthearted way:

> You're trying to trick me so you can put something disgusting in my
>   mouth, aren't you? Well I'm not going to let you trick me.

What's the right way to say `I don't trust you` in that sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably say something along the lines of:

> No me fio de ti (I don't trust you)
>
> A mi no me engañas (You won't trick me)